# Geometry and triangles problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question**:

> If D be the mid-point of AB and if the internal bisectors of $\angle ADC$ and $\angle BDC$ meet $AC$ and $BC$ at H and I respectively. Prove that $HI \parallel AB$

**My attempt**:

[image: diagram]

It is obvious that:

$\angle CDH = \angle HDA = a$ (let)
The fact that angles on a straight line sum to $180$ and that $\angle CDI = \angle IDB$ gives:
Then, $\angle CDI = \angle IDB = 90 - a$

Now, $\angle CDH + \angle CDI = a + (90 - a) = 90$.
Thus, $\triangle HID$ is right-angled.

This is all what I could, and I don't understand what to do next.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: At some stage you will need to use D being the mid-point of AB

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Angle Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fact that $DI$ bisects $\angle BDC$ gives ${CD \over DB} = {CI \over BI}.$ same  way,${CD \over AD} = {CH \over AH}.$  these two and $AD = BD$ shows ${CI \over BI} = {CH \over AH}.$  now you can conclude that $HI$ is parallel to $AB.$

Comment: Yes, I can now, thanks!